# Python Error IndexError: only integers

Tags: python, numpy

I am getting the following error when executing the code:
if (abs(arr[i] - val) < float(temp)):
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

**Code**

```
def closestval(arr, val):
temp = abs(arr[0] - val)
pos = 0
for i in arr:
    if abs(arr[i] - val) < temp:
        temp = abs(arr[i] - val)
        pos = i
return pos;
```

I am passing a list created by np.linspace, and the value 2*np.pi/2

**Code**

```
x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50, endpoint=True)

print(closestval(x, 2*np.pi/2))
```

Comment: Think it should be : `for i in range(len(arr)):` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python, when you iterate on an something, you get elements from that something.  You don't get the indices (at least not automatically)

```
In [262]: for i in ['a','b','c']:
     ...:     print(i)
     ...:     
a
b
c

In [264]: for i in np.arange(10,20,2):print(i)
10
12
14
16
18
In [265]: for i in range(4):print(i)
0
1
2
3
```

Effectively the last expression iterates on a list `[0,1,2,3]`.

So the expression:

```
for i in arr:
    print(arr[i])
```

does not make sense. `i` is element of `arr`, not an index.

This should work:

```
for a in arr:
    if abs(a - val) < temp:
        temp = abs(a - val)
        #pos = i
```

But since you need the index, `i`, the preferred python iteration is:

```
for i, a in enumerate(arr):
    av = abs(a - val)
    if av < temp:
        temp = av
        pos = i
```

where `enumerate` adds an index.  Keep this `enumerate` handy.

---

But this being `numpy` we don't need to iterate (at least not explicitly in Python)

```
In [266]: x = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50, endpoint=True)
In [267]: x<(2*np.pi/2)
Out[267]: 
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
In [268]: np.where(x<(2*np.pi/2))
Out[268]: 
(array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24], dtype=int32),)
In [269]: x[24:26]
Out[269]: array([ 3.07747852,  3.20570679])
```

We can compare every element of `x` with the target with one statement, and find the largest.

```
In [272]: np.max(np.where(x<(2*np.pi/2)))
Out[272]: 24

In [273]: np.argmin(x<(2*np.pi/2))
Out[273]: 25
```

There are various ways of determining the last element where the `<` test is True, or where it switches to False.

Comment: Also, if they want indices then they need to use either `for i, var in enumerate(arr):` which sets i as index and var as the item in index i of arr. Another option is `for i in range(len(arr)):`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am still very new to python, I am trying to plot a BPSK modulated signal.